# Detect automatically a network interface for each one in Solaris 11

Tags: networking, solaris

I'm working currently in a shell script to monitor a Solaris system. The main purpose of the script is show info like: Memory, Network, etc.

In the Network part, it will show info like arp table, available network interfaces, etc.

The thing is, the script is not only for a one system, so, the others have different nics. For example: for one of them I have the **net1**, and in an other I have **bge0**. I need to create a function to evaluate if the interface is net1 shows the result of this comand:

```
ifconfig -a | grep [network interface name]
```

The script will evaluate things like: if the OS is Solaris 10 then, show the nic available and ip that it use, in case that the OS will be a Solaris 11 then, show [other part....]

I hope to be very clear explaining this.

I used **`ifconfig`** command instead `ipadm` because I have Solaris 10 and Solaris 11 systems actually.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what information you want to display. There has been a lot of changes between Solaris 10 and 11, especially network virtualization (crossbow) / vanity naming. You can list all interfaces with `kstat -c net ":::link_state"` on both versions, but on the latter a single physical interface will show up more than once. There are also interfaces that might be partially or fully dedicated to non global zones, even kernel zones.

Comment: Make a system specific file for each system and include that at the top of your script.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You first need to call `ifconfig -a plumb` to get all potential interfaces plumbed before you can check the list.

Note that `ifconfig -a` only lists plumbed interfaces, while `ifconfig -a plumb` really applies to all interfaces - even those that are not yet plumbed.

Note that you cannot configure unplumbed interfaces. Regardless on whether you like to call `ifconfig xxx0 up` or `ifconfig xxx0 dhcp`. You first need to plumb an interface to make it usable. Even listing an interface via `ifconfig xxx0` will only work after it has been plumbed.

Comment: I use this command to list all network interfaces that I used in my so.

**`dladm show-link | awk '{print $1}'`**

Alternatively I use this one:

**`dladm show-phys`**

Comment: But this only works on newer Solaris versions. The `ifconfig -a plumb` method works always.

Comment: I got this message executing this command:

ifconfig: cannot plumb net1: Interface already exists
ifconfig: cannot plumb net0: Interface already exists

Comment: Not a problem. The command however grants you that all interfaces are plumbed when the command is ready. You now have access to all available interfaces.

Comment: If I want to hide that message to clearify my script out put, how can I do it?

Comment: Redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: You should not use `ifconfig -a plumb` on Solaris 11. You will use `ipadm` and `dladm` to configure network interfaces on Solaris 11.

Comment: Why not? It works. Your problem is to use a mixture of the old and new commands.

Comment: Why not,  it works is generally a bad idea. The answer I've given uses a) commands that both Solaris 10 and Solaris 11 have in common, b) to ease the programming by the OP to have the ability to create a generic function, c) does not change anything on the system (which monitoring is supposed to).

Comment: As mentioned before: you used a non-working mix. The reason why it does not work is that dladm lists more interfaces than ifconfig will list unless these interfaces have been plumbed.

Comment: @schily *Why not? It works.*  Not on my instance of Solaris 11.  This is the only output I get:  *ifconfig: cannot plumb net1: Interface already in use*  But `dladm show-phys` shows all links - unfortunately even the *non*-physical VirtualBox one `vboxnet0`.  I used `dladm show-phys -L` to show the actual physical location, which can be used to eliminate such virtual interfaces as they don't have a location and the output for the `vboxnet0` location shows as `--`.

Comment: Read the original answer from "Lambert": it does not work because it calls ifconfig with a list if names from dladm. This is the problem.

Comment: That is not the problem, that is intended to see if an interface is configured or not in an 'easy' way. As a side note, just looking for interfaces this way may not be sufficient if aggregated links (or IPMP) is being used.

Comment: @schily *Read the original answer from "Lambert": it does not work because it calls ifconfig with a list if names from dladm. This is the problem.*  I did read the original answer.  His answer is not relevant to whether or not `ifconfig -a plumb` works on Solaris 11.  From the single instance I have access to at the moment, it does not appear to work.

Comment: The answer in question contains a non-working command example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I do not fully understand your question but I read it as if you want to check if all the installed interfaces are configured or not.

To see installed interfaces, you can use `dladm show-link|grep -v "LINK"|awk '{print $1}'` on both to get a list of interface links.

You can use this list as input to retrieve the desired `ifconfig` output:

```
for NIC in $(dladm show-link|grep -v "LINK"|awk '{print $1}'); do ifconfig $NIC; done;
```

Comment: I got this error executing:

ifconfig: status: SIOCGLIFFLAGS: nxge0: no such interface
ifconfig: status: SIOCGLIFFLAGS: nxge1: no such interface
ifconfig: status: SIOCGLIFFLAGS: nxge2: no such interface
ifconfig: status: SIOCGLIFFLAGS: nxge3: no such interface

Comment: The proposed command has not been tested and it will not work. See my answer for a working method.

Comment: @schily, what makes you think this is a) not tested and b) not working? That the OP receives `nxge0: no such interface` messages just indicates that the interface is not configured. Another way is to iterate through the list and perform `ifconfig |grep "$NIC"` if you want to see output only for configured entries. But in that case, why filtering for an interface at all instead of parsing `ifconfig -a` output?

Comment: No, it indicated that the interface has not been plumbed. This is why your script fails: It does not do the needed plumbing.

Comment: To avoid a long discussion, but is 'not configured' in this case not equal to 'not plumbed'?

Comment: @Lambert *is 'not configured' in this case not equal to 'not plumbed'?*  Yes, it is.